# How to check the actual hour and depending on the result add the id to a specific class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, loops

```
var checkTime = function(){


    for(var i = 9; i <= 17; i++){
        if($.now() < i){
            $("#hour-").addClass(".past");
        }
        if($.now()  === i){
            $("#hour-").addClass(".present");
        }
        if ($.now()  > i) {
            $("hour-").addClass(".future");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to set a color "class 'past' 'present' 'future' depending on the hour in which the user logged into the website, between 9am to 5pm. I have set ids for every hour starting by hour-9 hour-10.. and so on until hour-17. Not quite sure how to handle this, thank you if you tried to solve this

Comment: Did you check what `$.now()` returns? Also without seeing your html, it's a bit hard to give you a clear answer, but I think that you will have a problem with all these if statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can make your code more efficient by remvoing the loop and only use the conditions but you need to use `else if` as you only need one condition to be true at a time but your code can have multiple true statements. Also, i have removed `.` from class names as well you dont need to add them it is used to declare the class only.

```
var checkTime = function(){
    var dt = new Date();
    var currHour=dt.getHour();
    if(currHour < 9){
        $("#hour-").addClass("past");
    }
    else if(currHour  === 9){
        $("#hour-").addClass("present");
    }
    else if(currHour  > 9) {
        $("hour-").addClass("future");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked what `$.now()` returns? For an example right now it returns `1657519415875`

Comment: @CarstenAndersen Hi, sorry i did not check that, thankyou for reminding me, I have edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

I use three background colors to represent the past, present, and future.

`checkTime` will be based on the input hours (login hours), to compare with the current hours, and assign a class

```js
//Initial login hours
{
  const date = new Date($.now());
  $('input[type=text]').val(date.getHours());
}

//Switch class based on login hour
const checkTime = (loginHours) => {
  const date = new Date($.now());
  if (loginHours < date.getHours()) {
    $('div').removeClass().addClass('past');
  } else if (loginHours == date.getHours()) {
    $('div').removeClass().addClass('present');
  } else {
    $('div').removeClass().addClass('future');
  }
};

//Add a listener and call the method
$('input[type=button]').on('click', () => {
  const loginHours = $('input[type=text]').val();
  checkTime(loginHours);
});
```

```css
.past {
  background-color: #FFD382;
}

.present {
  background-color: #82FF82;
}

.future {
  background-color: #30FFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" placeholder="login hours" />
<input type="button" value="SUBMIT" />
<div>TEST DIV</div>
```